# How to display categories in all page?

Tags: magento

Am a Magento beginer

In my index page am adding categories

I have other 2 pages

I want all my 3 pages showing the categories as in the index page also the categories shows in the same side

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guyz Atlast i solve the problem

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
```

am add this to `left.phtml` and solve the problem

Thanks for help guyz

Comment: Haven't tried but I don't think it would be loaded in every page especially pages with layout ---> 2-col-right, 1-col, empty.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding,I concluded with this solution Write this part in path: magento_folder/app/design/frontend/mytheme(your_package_folder)/neo(your_theme_folder)/layout/local.xml
Create it if not found.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
  <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
                    <label>Navigation Bar</label>
                    <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
                </block>
</default>
</layout>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Writing the above code , by default it (categories) would be loaded in every page.